# PHP: replace relative top URL "../" with absolute domain URL

Tags: php, url, preg-replace, relative-url

I want to convert relative URLs that starts with `../stuff/more.php` to `http://www.example.com/stuff/more.php` in my RSS feed.

I used this PHP code to do so is the following:

```
$content = preg_replace("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)#", '$1http://www.example.com/$2$3', $content);
```

The result is wrong thought, it returns the URL like this

`http://www.example.com/../stuff/more.php`

Notice the `../` part hasn't been removed, please help!

**So Basically..**

This what I have: `../stuff/more.php`

This is what I get (after running the code above): `http://www.example.com/../stuff/more.php`

This what I WANT: `http://www.example.com/stuff/more.php`

Comment: Can anyone please provide me with the syntax of "../" is `([..\"'>]+)` correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding (\.|\.\.|\/)* should work.

$content = preg_replace("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)(../|../|/)*([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)#", '$1http://www.example.com/$3$4', $content);

Also, note $2$3 has been changed to $3$4

Edit:

Reduced to one alternative:

```
    $content = preg_replace("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)(\.\.\/)*([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)#", '$1http://www.example.com/$3$4', $content);
```

Comment: actually it didn't work either, but you are in the right track. I want the code to search for this exactly `href="../` and replace it with this exactly `href="=http://www.example.com/`

Comment: @user4697489 please tell me the format to write this `href="../`

Comment: I would cut it down to 1 alternative:  (\.\.\/)*

Comment: I made this code `$content = preg_replace("#(<a href=\"\.\.\/)#", '<a href="http://www.example.com/', $content);` based on your suggestion. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just replace the first 2 dots with the domain?

```
$result = str_replace('..', 'http://www.example.com', $contet, 1);
```

Comment: the code in the first is required to detect the relative URL

Comment: Isn't that it? Or are there other cases?

Comment: I want to add "../" syntax to my current code. the RSS has mixed urls, some with http:// and some with ../

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` is the global variable in PHP to get the absolute url.

Comment: You can also use explode and implode to get rid of starting `../`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll start looking at the regex. Most of it looks good (in fact, you've got a good enough regex here I'm a little surprised you're having trouble otherwise!) but the end is a bit weird -- better like this:

```
#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)([\"']>)#
```

(Technically it would be better to capture the starting quote and make sure it's a matching ending quote, but chances are you won't have any problems there.

To remove the `../` I would do it apart from regex entirely:

```
foreach (array("<a href=\"http://../foo/bar\">", 
        "<a href=\"../foo/bar\">") as $content) {
    echo "A content=$content<br />\n";
    ########## copy from here down to...
    if (preg_match("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*?href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)([\"']>)#", $content, $m)) {
        echo "m=<pre>".print_r($m,true)."</pre><br />\n";
        if (substr($m[2], 0, 3) == '../')
            $m[2] = substr($m[2], 3);
        $content = $m[1].'http://www.example.com/'.$m[2].$m[3];
    }
    ######### copy from above down to HERE
    echo "B content=$content<br />\n";
}
```

(I included a mini-test suite around what you're looking for - you will need to take just the marked lines inside for your code.)

Comment: can you please tell me how to add "../" syntax to my existing code ?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "your code didn't work"?

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't replace the "../" on the RSS feed

Comment: I can provide you with the RSS link and full php code in private chat if you want to help

Comment: Copy my exact mini-test into a new php file with the `<?php` tag at the top of it. Run it on your server. If it works then figure out what problem is occurring between my code and yours. If it doesn't work then tell me what results you are getting. I run it on my server and it gives me great results, leaving the `http://...` url untouched and changing the `../...` url to use the example.com.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to everyone who helped me on this.
Here's the code I used:

```
$content = preg_replace("#(<a href=\"\.\.\/)#", '<a href="http://www.example.com/', $content);
```

it searches for `<a href="../` and replace it with `http://www.example.com/` it's not general but this works for me.